# How to display cart items in popup in Vue js?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I am trying to display cart items in popup in Vue js

I am having trouble with only displaying items that are added in cart item.

Here is the working code pen - https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-pine-8u9mt?file=/src/main.js

Comment: Please add the relevant code to your question as code blocks, this question becomes useless if (/when!) the link dies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pop can be created using bootstrap & modified 
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/